# How to make the most of JBOSS in multicore environments

Tags: jboss, threads, multi-core

I'm deploying jboss in a multicore system, where I'll have from 12 to 20 cores, and when I run the jboss server, I only see 1 process running, and I feel like it won't use more than one core...

Is there any way of using more cores or jboss is smart and under that process is it using more threads or something?

I'm using AIX 6.1 on a Power7 system.
JVM J9 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using JBoss EAP 4.3 on dual-processor/dual-core and dual-processor/quad-core Dell PowerEdge servers. When we load-test the JBoss application, all the cores are in use (at varying levels) simultaneously. The bulk of the work is being done by the application, as our database usage is mostly write-only.

Also, as Ronald indicated, it is always best to find appropriate performance-monitoring tools for your environment.

Answer (score 2):

It should be multi threaded, you should be able to see mentions of thread counts in the logs (well, I know websphere and ATG Dynamo better, but much the same).  Not that you cannot screw it up with a bad configuration. Read up on performance monitoring for your OS.